# What is the new URL schema for Here WeGo v4 on iOS/Android?

Tags: here-api, here-wego

The URL schema for Here WeGo on iOS and Android changed with version 4.  It's no longer `here-location://`, `here-route://`, and `here-place://`.

I looked at the metadata and can see it's now just `wego://` for everything, but that's all I can get from the metadata.  From trial and error it looks like `wego://route` causes the app to launch as if I had passed it a route, however everything I've tried (e.g. `wego://route/mylocation/37.870090,-122.268150`) results in it just sitting there with my current location as the start and destination.  Similar behavior for `location` and `place`.

It looks like the old documentation for the URL schema was removed from the developer portal, and either wasn't replaced with updated docs, or has been moved to somewhere hard to find.

Can someone from the Here team please post the updated schema information?  Thanks!!

Comment: I assume you want to pass in information to the new HERE WeGo app from another app and then launch it, for example to show a route?

Comment: I was actually trying to create QR codes to launch the Here WeGo app with a route.  The idea was to have these printed on an itinerary for a multi-day trip where offline maps would need to be used (due to no cellular coverage).  The app-to-app scenario you mentioned would probably be useful for some people too though.

Comment: The HERE Deeplinking API provides solutions for:
Sharing a place or address
Sharing a route or itinerary
Sharing a location
You can trigger sharing on the web or a native Deeplinking API application. A web browser or on a mobile device with a Deeplinking API application installed can receive and open the shared URL.
Each request must conform to the following format: 
http://share.here.com/{share_object}/
{share_object_path_params}
?{query_params}

For more details:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/dev_guide/topics/request-format.html

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport this opens in Safari. I'd like to open the route in the Here WeGo app. Using the `here-route://` scheme works but I can't find a way to specify the transport mode. The `m=w` query parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is over a year old but I since it keeps coming up on the top of Google search, I wanted to share an updated.

I have found that you can use the computed URL of https://share.here.com/r/latitude,longitude,place_name?m=d&t=normal (substituting latitude,longtitude and place_name, of course).

The first time you open this URL, you get prompted by Safari (or your default browser) to open Here WeGo.  If you choose "Allow Always" then subsequent links go directly into the navigation panel with the destination being the address you specify.

You can also write some interesting Shortcuts that allow you to search your Contacts for an address, convert that into lat/long and then go directly to the navigation.

I guess if you could capture the internal URL that the share.here.com sends back, you could determine the direct internal link.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are Googling:

- add "wego" to the [Queried URL Schemes] item in the info.plist file
- write this function

  ```
  func coordinate(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, label:String) {
       let phonePoint = String(format: "https://share.here.com/l/%f,%f,%@", location.latitude,  location.longitude,
                           label.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) ?? "")
       if let phoneURLMaps = URL(string: phoneSt) {
           let phonOpen = String(format: "wego://route/mylocation/%f,%f,%",location.latitude, location.longitude
           if let phonOpenLMaps = URL(string: phonOpen) {
              if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(phonOpenLMaps) {
                 UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURLMaps, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
              }
           }
       }
  }
  ```